# Question about safety of simple PHP encryption / decryption

Tags: php, encryption, xor

Hello and thank you for taking your time to help me.

I am developing a Web App and I need to encrypt some info/strings that are passed with GET request and I don't want somebody to be able to read it, easily break encryption or be able to brute-force it.

So I've come up with this piece of code to encrypt/decrypt it

```
function encriptDecript($string, $key) {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
            // the brain of this code is this, i think its XOR, but not sure if I did it the right way
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($string[$i]) ^ $key);

            //btw I have also tried this which makes it possible to put strings as keys i guess? idk im confused
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($string[$i]) ^ ord($key) );
    return $string;
}
echo encriptDecript("Random sentence", 17);
```

The one thing that bugs me is how simple this function is (**especially** the key).

I have this picture in my mind that someone who is experienced will know that they are dealing with XOR could just make random Python script or something to brute-force this with like 17 tries (since my key is 17).

Btw they can know what will be encrypted since they supply the "Random sentence", the only thing they have to do is to guess my key -> which is "17" (**ultra-guessable**)

Am I right or this code is unbreakable? Pls suggest a better way if I am wrong, but keep in mind that it has to be two-way encyption (not like hash).

Also pls keep in mind that I am begginer, a lot of things go over my head haha.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone All encryption is just "moving bits". If you don't know what it's being XORed with, it's encryption.

Comment: @Barmar is this simple key (17) really making it impossible for the attacker to guess it?

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the data from? You can use HTTPS to encrypt it much more effectively on the network. If you're trying to hide it from the user, it won't work, since they can simply find the place in the JavaScript that decrypts it.

Comment: It doesn't matter how fancy the encryption algorithm is -- eventually the app has to decode it, and the user can view the decrypted data.

Comment: opinion-based, imo use AES or don't bother

Comment: @Barmar the user will not interact with code, the code will carry user email and reset key (in GET request) so he/she can reset the password and I am trying to protect this info by encryption and I am wondering how safe is this way?

Comment: What you've created here is essentially a basic Caesar Cipher and it is trivially breakable. Just set up SSL.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they normally interact with it. If they want to find the secret message, they can set a breakpoint in the code. What threat model are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @Sammitch can you provide some sources to SSL encryption?

Comment: The user can open Developer Tools and see things that the application doesn't deliberately show them.

Comment: @Barmar I think you don't understand me, my question is: If they get the encrypted key, even if I hand it to them in big letters, will they be able to guess it if this encryption is used?

Comment: So this is something like a random string in a URL that they follow to get to a password reset or account confirmation page?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would want to encrypt that. The reset key should just be random data with no meaning at all, so there's no point in keeping it secret. To answer the question: no, simple xor is not safe at all. It's the very first thing that's broken in any cryptanalysis class.